# Output an entries object hierarchy with all the data

Tags: powershell

Take the below object called $ret3

```
$ret = [ordered]@{
        Title = "ABC"
        Data = "FFFFF"}

$ret2 = [ordered]@{
        Title = "ABC"
        Data = $ret}

$ret3 = [ordered]@{
        Title = "ABC"
        Data = $ret2}
```

All the below methods do not travers the entire object hierarchy and output the members and its data for all of them. Is there a way to do this in PS ?

```
$ret3 

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Title                          ABC                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Data                           {Title, Data}    

$ret3 | Format-Table

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Title                          ABC                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Data                           {Title, Data}
```

Comment: `$ret3 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9`? or if you want PowerShell notation: [`$ret3 | ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is what you are looking for but you can simply pipe the object to the [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.3&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet to get the entire object hierarchy:

```
$ret3 | ConvertTo-Json
```

**output:**

```
{
  "Title": "ABC",
  "Data": {
    "Title": "ABC",
    "Data": {
      "Title": "ABC",
      "Data": "FFFFF"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this, the not reinventing the wheel style of answer ;)